# Do worldwide datacenters have global/standard unique code or name?

Tags: datacenter, iso

Some datacenter providers have 3-4 letter codes for their locations. However, it seems there is not international standards for this?

Comment: What value would there be in such a standard existing? One organization's set of names would not matter *at all* outside of that organization.

Comment: I would venture they are simply internal naming conventions that people gleam from over the years and incorporate themselves.  We used things like CODENPRI for instance (Colorado, Denver, Primary), after seeing others use the same nomenclature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do worldwide datacenters have global/standard unique code or name?

If you mean 'is there a standard that everyone uses' then no, there's not - but specific data center owners will I'm sure have location specifiers for their own sites, but these will vary from company to company.

Comment: I guess its because anybody can build a server room/shack in their backyard, hook up an ADSL line with a fixed IP (or two) and call it a new datacenter? :)

Comment: I'm not sure there's a great demand for such an identifier - plus there are very many 'hidden' data centers that really don't want their locations known.

Comment: To rephrase my not so serious follow up above: is there no authority who ranks/audits/certifies DCs?

Comment: I'm unaware of any but if you ask this as a new question I think that would be valid and may get a better answer than your comment ok.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen closest airport's [IATA code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_airport_code) often being used, but I think it is way too far from being standard.

Comment: I've seen this as well as abbreviated city names (like "bos" for boston).

Comment: Good point about IATA. Actually ISO_3166-2 could also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In theory CLLI could be used for this, although in practice that is an awkward solution and not really necessary (and not all datacentre operators are necessarily involved with telecordia).  There isn't a standard for this mainly because the names of a company's various sites are of no technical significance whatsoever, and no problems arise from them being completely arbitrary.